# Implementing a bilateral filter

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, dynamic-programming

I am trying to implement a bilateral filter from the paper [Fast Bilateral Filteringfor the Display of High-Dynamic-Range Images](https://people.csail.mit.edu/fredo/PUBLI/Siggraph2002/DurandBilateral.pdf). The equation (from the paper) that implements the bilateral filter is given as :

[image]

According to what I understood,

- f is a Gaussian filter
- g is a Gaussian filter
- p is a pixel in a given image window
- s is the current pixel
- Ip is the intensity at the current pixel

With this, I wrote the code to implement these equations, given as :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("fish.png")
# image of width 239 and height 200



bl_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

i = cv2.magnitude(
    cv2.Sobel(bl_img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3),
    cv2.Sobel(bl_img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
)

f = cv2.getGaussianKernel(5, 0.1, cv2.CV_64F)
g = cv2.getGaussianKernel(5, 0.1, cv2.CV_64F)


rows, cols, _ = img.shape

filtered = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=img.dtype)

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        ks = []
        for index in [-2,-1,1,2]:
            if index + c > 0 and index + c < cols-1:
                p = img[r][index + c]
                s = img[r][c]
                i_p = i[index+c]
                i_s = i[c]
                ks.append(
                    (f * (p-s)) * (g * (i_p * i_s)) # EQUATION 7
                )
        ks = np.sum(np.array(ks))

        js = []
        for index in [-2, -1, 1, 2]:
            if index + c > 0 and index + c < cols -1:
                p = img[r][index + c]
                s = img[r][c]
                i_p = i[index+c]
                i_s = i[c]
                js.append((f * (p-s)) * (g * (i_p * i_s)) * i_p) # EQUATION 6

        js = np.sum(np.asarray(js))
        js = js / ks
        filtered[r][c] = js

cv2.imwrite("f.png", filtered)
```

But as I run this code I get an error saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bft.py", line 33, in <module>
    (f * (p-s)) * (g * (i_p * i_s))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,3) (5,239)
```

Did I incorrectly implement the equations? What am I missing?

Comment: your matrix shapes are incompatible, you can not multiply a matrix with dimensions 5,3 to another matrix with dimension 5,239

Comment: @prhmma Would you know the correct way to code the above equation?

Comment: change these two lines and check if it work `ks.append(np.matmul((f * (p-s)).T, (g * (i_p - i_s))) # EQUATION 7` and `js.append(np.matmul((f * (p-s)).T, (g * (i_p * i_s)) * i_p)) # EQUATION 6`

Comment: @prhmma Not sure if this is a matrix multiplication

Comment: You need to index the Gaussian kernel (or better yet use interpolation). *f(p-s)* in the equation means evaluating the Gaussian at *p-s*.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Okay. What would be the value of neighbors? Are they the adjacent pixels to the current pixel? (top, right, bottom, left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various issues with your code. Foremost, the equation is interpreted in a wrong way. *f(p-s)* means evaluating the function *f* at *p-s*. *f* is the Gaussian. Likewise with *g*. The section of the code would look like this:

```py
weight = gaussian(p - s, sigma_f) * gaussian(i_p - i_s, sigma_g)
ks.append(weight)
js.append(weight * i_p)
```

Note that the two loops can be merged, this way you avoid some duplicated computation. `gaussian(x, sigma)` would be a function that computes the Gaussian weight at `x`. You need to define two sigmas, `sigma_f` and `sigma_g`, the spatial and the tonal sigma respectively.

The second issue is in the definition of `p` and `s`. These are the *coordinates* of the pixel, not the value of the image at the pixel. `i_p` and `i_s` are the value of the image at those locations. `p-s` is basically the spatial distance between the pixel at `(r,c)` and the given neighbor.

The third issue is the loop over the neighborhood. The neighborhood is all pixels where `gaussian(p - s, sigma_f)` is not negligible. So how large the neighborhood is depends on the chosen `sigma_f`. You should take it at least to be `ceil(2*sigma_f)`. Say `sigma_f` is 2, then you want the neighborhood to go from -4 to 4 (9 pixels). But this neighborhood is two dimensional, not one-dimensional as in your code. So you need two loops:

```py
for ii in range(-ceil(2*sigma_f), ceil(2*sigma_f)+1):
   if ii + c > 0 and ii + c < cols-1:
   for jj in range(-ceil(2*sigma_f), ceil(2*sigma_f)+1):
      if jj + r > 0 and jj + r < rows-1:
         # compute weight here
```

Note that now, `p-s` is computed with `math.sqrt(ii**2 + jj**2)`. But also note that the Gaussian uses `x**2`, so you could skip the computation of the square root by passing `x**2` into your `gaussian` function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was going through a resource at http://people.csail.mit.edu/sparis/bf_course/slides/06_implementation.pdf that describes different ways to implement BF. Could you point me to a source (or paper) that implements BF utilizing the `ceil(2*sigma_f)` for the neighbors?

Comment: Also what would it mean if I supply the value of neighbors to the algorithm such that `total neighbors != ceil(2*sigma_f)`. What would this mean?

Comment: @Amanda: The original paper ([Tomasi and Manduchi, 1998](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~manduchi/Papers/ICCV98.pdf)) proposing the bilateral filter shows an example where the cutoff is close to 2 sigma (23 pixels for a sigma of 5). The equations there show infinite integrals (i.e. summing over the whole image domain). The concept of cutting off at 2 sigma is that further out the Gaussian will have quite small values (for normal Gaussian filtering I always use at least 3 sigma, but the bilateral filter doesn't require that much precision).

Comment: @Amanda: At the edge of the image you'll find fewer pixels in the neighborhood. This is fine because of the way that the filter is normalized. You always divide by the sum of the filter weights. If your question relates instead to making the neighborhood smaller than 2 sigma (lowering the cutoff), then the effect is that the spatial Gaussian shape will be truncated, leading to a non-Gaussian shape. You might as well use uniform weights in that case. Filters with uniform weights have much worse properties that those with Gaussian weights.

Comment: @Amanda: In [this blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695) I discuss the effect of reducing the cutoff of the Gaussian filter.